# Validity of a uri template according to URITemplate specification

Tags: url, rest, wildcard, uritemplate

Is '/abc/foo/{id}/bar/*' a valid template according to URITemplate specification? Or the url s with only {} are valid? i.e. /abc/foo/bar/{path}.

In the first case, /abc/foo/4/random/new.jgp will be mapped to /abc/foo/{id}/bar/*
In the second case, /abc/foo/4/random/new.jgp will be mapped to /abc/foo/bar/{path}, considering path=random/new.jpg

So which is the valid notation?